# Replacing C++ while loop with std/boost algorithm

Tags: c++

I have a while-loop that I'd like to replace with an std/boost algorithm (largely for my learning, along the line of Sean Parent's [no-raw-loops maxim](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning)).

```
std::queue q;
while (! q.empty()) {
    auto front = q.front();
    q.pop();
    do_stuff_with_front();
    potentially_insert_more_into_q();
}
```

As you can see, I conditionally enqueue more elements within the loop; think maze traversal. What std/boost algorithm may be suitable for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't think of any algorithm or alternate approach that will yield code more clear than the while loop you've already written. All standard algorithms I can remember work on a fixed range, and since your code is adding elements that's not consistent with standard algorithm interfaces.

Comment: + Afaik, all the algorithms use iterators, which are invalidated on an insert. You would need to re-initialize the iterators on every insert. The OP could try making an abstraction that does this.